# curl tlsv1.2 option not working

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

I have 2 Linux systems where the command ->  curl -V -> shows the below

**System-1**

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

**System-2**

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

If I try a curl command using tlsv1.2 option on **System-1** , it throws an error -

```
[root@ssclnx1 ~]# curl -k -1 --tlsv1.2 --user user:pass -X GET https://HOST:9443/console/deploymnt/login 
curl: option --tlsv1.2: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Same command works fine on **System-2**.

The only difference between the curl version in the two system is -

```
NSS/3.16.2.3
NSS/3.19.1
```

What is NSS exactly? What lib\jar\utility I need to upgrade in order to upgrade the NSS to 3.19.1 ? 
I have to give a general recommendation to the customer so that the curl tlsv1.2 option would work. 
Please suggest. I am blocked on this.

Thanks in advance -

Abhijit.

Comment: This is more a system administration question than a software development question -- I'm not sure that StackOverflow is the best choice of venues. The bigger issue is that just upgrading your NSS isn't likely to help without *also* recompiling curl, unless that's a runtime check (which wouldn't be common practice here).

Comment: ...and, well, in general, all of these are packages your Linux distributor should be compiling for you -- if you or your customer is building them yourselves, there's an argument to be made that that's Part Of The Problem re: why you have systems with inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> What is NSS exactly?

The Network Security Services Library. This is the TLS library used by Mozilla (Firefox) and in parts by Chrome. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS.

> What lib\jar\utility I need to upgrade in order to upgrade the NSS to 3.19.1

I doubt that just upgrading the library will help. NSS support TLS 1.2 since version 3.15.1 but when building curl it was probably decided to not build curl with TLS 1.2 support enabled. Thus it might be enough to rebuild curl and make sure to include TLS 1.2 support. The problem might also be solved if you upgrade your system.

Comment: The `--tlsv1.2` option was added in curl 7.34.0 so no older version can ask specifically for 1.2, you could only ask for "TLS" back then.

Comment: @DanielStenberg: in this case the vendor (Redhat I assume) probably backported the option to curl 7.19.7 but only for selected OS versions. Because according to the OP the option exists on System-2.

Comment: I realize that is stated, but it also seems like a rather hefty backport (that I've not heard of before) so I'm not entirely convinced we get the correct info here.